# Recommended dimensions for a house, in an architecture project

Tags: architecture, project-planning

Is there any website (or maybe a book) with recommended dimensions for a house, in an architecture project? For instance: What is the recommended size for a passageway? What is the recommended inclination for a stair? What is the recommended inclination for a roof? Etc. It would be very nice if some architecture department (from some university) could have this kind of information on the web. I can find each information searching one by one, but not a comprehensive list.

The area51-architecture is closed, so maybe diy-home-improvement is the better place to ask this question.

Comment: For stairs, passageways, doors and similar stuff just look what is around you.  Most other stuff, roofs, sizes, are personal likes mainly.  Roofs go from flat to steep A-frames.  You might want structural engineering books.

Comment: You appear to  be looking for architechural standards, which should be in books, and perhaps other media. Some can also be found as code (i.e. IRC standards for minmum width of a hallway, etc.) Some things you mention are not stndards, nor standardized - roof slope range from 1/8" per foot to 14 inches per foot, for example, and suitable choices vary by area and climate and personal choice.

Comment: For a roof, the house I grew up in, had the peak running front to back and off set by a 1/4 to 1/3 side to side.  So one steeper side and the other a low slope.  I thought it was common till I started riding my bike further away from home.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This list is only a sample, I have many others that I need to look for. Anyway, I know how to use 3D modeling tools (DIY, of course), before sending the project to some professional (in architecture) to implement it.

Comment: Asphalt shingle manufacturers prefer a roof slope of 4:12 but will tolerate 2:12 if you throw enough money at the problem. I've always assumed that this is where the typical roof slope of 4:12 comes from. https://www.amazon.com/Residential-Interior-Design-Planning-Spaces/dp/1119653428/ is aesthetically driven but mentions code constraints also. That's a good starting place for following Amazon's algorithm, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like [architectural standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111890950X).

You will most likely need to purchase a book, or subscribe to a website as having all the information composed in a complete format is someone's intellectual property and not accessible for free on the net.

If you do not want to spend money to subscribe/ purchase, you will have to spend time searching for each piece of information.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this book.